# Is a Public key from a certificate always valid?

Tags: java, ssl, certificate

Okay so i have a .cer file which has a certificate key like

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
.....A1NuUYdviJSQOLhkL8WgtEpocv1u2mv9DQcMJWoA
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I am using this public key to verify a response i get from a third party server. I am using the

```
Signature.verify
```

method of java security. My issue is that even if i tamper the certificate like

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
.....A1NuUYdviJSQOLhkL8WgtEpocv1u2mv9DQcMJ111
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I am still able to verify my data. Am i doing something wrong or am i not understanding something.

Answer (score 1):

Certificate contains more than just a public key. You probably changed some other field (but I am surprised you didn't get any complaints, it should be signed).

You can try to have a look at certificate content with:

```
openssl x509 -noout -text -in <filename>
```

and see for yourself what changed.

Comment: Okay so i found the difference by making the changes as mentioned in the question there was change in the  Signature Algorithm of the certificate and not the Public Key Algorithm. Hence i was able to verify my data as the Public Key Algorithm was in matching with the private key.